# How to assign waiters to a restaurant operation simulation in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

i'm new to AnyLogic and i started using it for a restaurant operations simulation. Right now i've figured out how to use the pedestrian library to simulate customers coming into my restaurant and go to attractors placed around the dining tables and make them stop there for a period of time. However, i need help assigning a few waiters who go to each of the customers at least once after they have "sat down at their seats" (or simply means reaching and stopping at the attractors). i cannot figure out whether i can keep using pedestrian library or i have to use another library like a process handling library or create new agents as i am not familiar with the software. any help is much appreciated!

attached below are screenshots of the model and the blocks i currently have done:

model: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0siO2.jpg
blocks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0ekr.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I assume there are a lot of ways to do this... Normally you would use waiters as resources, but I think you can't make resources behave like pedestrians if you mix it with the Process Modeling Library... If you can do it smoothly maybe someone will answer it

What you can do is something like this:
[image: waiters and customers]
On this model you have a separate flow for the waiters, who are your resources and you have to use some JAVA to seize the waiters for a particular table and allow them to do something... do what? I don't know, that depends on your model.

This is just a guideline for one possible solution but there are a lot of implications on how to actually implement it correctly.

Comment: Hello Sir, can i know under which library is the second block in blue (waitForCustomers) from? i can't seem to find it in any of the libraries.. for reference i am currently using the 8.4.0 Personal Learning Edition. Also for the JAVA part from your comment, i have no knowledge in coding nor JAVA so can i know how to model the waiters to simply go to one of the attractors that i have set for a short period of time and then they can leave and go to other attractors for a same period of time and so on, they don't have to carry out any other activities.

Comment: That block belongs to the Process Modeling library (it's on the bottom where it says auxiliary blocks)... one of my favorite blocks to use... but requires JAVA.

I can't tell you how to model the waiters... it's not so simple as to answer it in 3 sentences.... and you need to learn JAVA and AnyLogic in general, and how to model, because even if you manage to do the waiters, you will have new problems later.... because you don't know the blocks... and without JAVA you can't do interesting things as the one you want to do now.

Comment: Alright Sir.. i found the block and i arranged new block flows according to the one you posted above. Can i know how to set the properties of the pedSouce(waiters) so that i have 2 waiters that spawn right at first and will keep staying throughout the simulation? Because when i set the arrival rate to 2 waiters per day(i will only run the simulation for 8 hours) and i run the simulation, they do not show up at all and im guessing i cannot set it that way.. also for the blue "Wait" block, can you briefly explain how do i set the properties so that it suits my objectives stated at first? Thanks!

Comment: use the documentation to understand the wait block, and use the documentation to understand the pedSource block, in particular the function inject()... you will do in the main setup waiters.inject(2) ... 

Lesson here: Learn that investigation the AnyLogic documentation is one of the most important things you can do as a modeler... I highly suggest for you use the documentation, review the examples and all that stuff one needs to do to be able to do simple models

Comment: Alright Sir, thank you very much but i think i still need someone to guide me through the JAVA part and some of the properties settings as i am stuck with lots of problems now. Also the online notes of AnyLogic help have limited information for my work. I studied the notes about the wait block but still i tried to set it somehow i have infinity spawning of waiters when i use the arrival method of rate schedule when i only put 2 waiters

Comment: This is how i set my arrival schedule: https://imgur.com/a/WjGH5FO (i set repeat every 7 days because i'll only run the simulation for 8 hrs and i just have to make sure it doesn't repeat in that period) but i'm not sure if that's what it means.. I also have limited time to finish this project, sorry to say but i might need someone to spoonfeed me with codes.. maybe i'll try and post another question later on just for the JAVA codes